# Find each cell value of a range in SAP table (gridview)

Tags: vba, excel, sap-gui

I'm trying to look for a specific text from my excel file to a SAP table.

I have tried below code but it gives me error "Invalid Next Control variable reference"

So far below is my code:

```
set rLastRow = rSheet.Cells(rSheet.rows.Count, "AO").End(xlUp).Row
Set Table = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell")

rows = Table.RowCount - 1
cols = Table.RowCount - 1


Dim columns As Object
Set columns = Table.ColumnOrder

For i = 0 To rows

For j = 2 To rLastRow


If rSheet.Cells(j, "AO").Value = Table.GetCellValue(i, columns(3)) Then

 MsgBox "Found!" & rSheet.Cells(j, "AO").Value & Table.GetCellValue(i, columns(3)), vbOKOnly

Else

'proceed to next value to find

End If

Next i

Next j
```

What I'm trying to do is for each cell in range "AO" in excel, it will look for a match in my GridView  (SAP: fbl3n).

Is there another way where can I loop to each cell from range (excel) and look for it in a SAP table (GridView)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the report is displayed as a grid, you could try the following:

```
Sub Test()
'
' Test Makro
'
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SAPApplication = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = SAPApplication.Children(0)
Set session = Connection.Children(0)

rLastRow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
Set Table = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell")

allRows = Table.RowCount - 1

Dim columns As Object
Set columns = Table.ColumnOrder

For i = 2 To rLastRow
'MsgBox Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 41).Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 41).Select

 For j = 0 To allRows
 'MsgBox Table.GetCellValue(j, columns(3))

  If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 41).Value = Val(Table.GetCellValue(j, columns(3))) Then
   Table.setCurrentCell j, ""
   Table.selectedRows = j
   MsgBox "Found: " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 41).Value & " / " &   Table.GetCellValue(j, columns(3)), vbOKOnly
  End If

 Next
Next
'
End Sub
```

Regards, 
ScriptMan

Comment: Thank you ScriptMan! I will try this. Question, is there a method in ALV GridView that I can use similar with excel Range.Find?

Comment: You can find out it for yourself: http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FGetCellValueMethodSapGridView_ref.html

Comment: With the link above I have just seen that you have first to search for "gridview" and then click on "sapgridview class".

Comment: Thanks a lot ScriptMan! I am now able to achieve what I need to do with the solution you provided. I also checked the documentation you gave and able to familiarize the SAP GridView methods. :)

Comment: Hi ScriptMan, I would just like to ask again regarding the DoubleClick. If my data is found in the sap Grid, I would like to doubleclick it as I need to edit some text for that certain item. I tried to add the Table.DoubleClickCurrentCell, but it seems that it is not working and just continue looping. Would you mind if you can advise on this? Thank you.

Comment: Hello ScriptMan, I found out that I need to change Table.setCurrentCell j, "" 
to sTable.CurrentCellRow = j. Thank you!

Comment: Then the link to the documentation of Microfocus was the right one. ;-)

Comment: The documentation link doesn't work anymore. This one currently works: [GuiGridView Object](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/sap_gui_for_windows/latest/en-US?q=GuiGridView).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know SAP, however I would

1. remove `Set` in front of rLastRow becasuse `rSheet.Cells(rSheet.rows.Count, "AO").End(xlUp).Row` returns a `Long`. The reason of the error message may be here as `Set` autodeclares `Object` that can not be used for `For`
2. use `Option Explicit`
3. not use `rows` and `columns` as variable name for `Rows` and `Columns` are keywords of VBA that may lead to confusions
4. check the status after each `Set` whether the assignment is OK, e.g.:

   ```
   Set columns = Table.ColumnOrder
   If columns is Nothing Then <...escape from here...>
   ```